# OnClick listner in table row

Tags: java, android, onclick, row, tableview

I have created an activity containing a tableview. The header and the table rows are added to the tableview dynamically through the activity. All are working fine, but I am not understanding how to add onClick listner to all rows except the header, and get the values of the columns in the particular row.

This is the **full code of the activity**:

```
public class ReportListActivity extends Activity {

    TableLayout report_table;
    TableRow tr_data;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_report_list);

        report_table=(TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.report_table);


        //---------------Table Header-----------------------------------------------
        TableRow tr_head = new TableRow(this);
        tr_head.setId(10);
        tr_head.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        tr_head.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


        TextView label_sr_no = new TextView(this);
        label_sr_no.setId(20);
        label_sr_no.setText("S.No.");
        label_sr_no.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        label_sr_no.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
        tr_head.addView(label_sr_no);// add the column to the table row here

        TextView label_test_name = new TextView(this);
        label_test_name.setId(21);// define id that must be unique
        label_test_name.setText("Test Name"); // set the text for the header 
        label_test_name.setTextColor(Color.WHITE); // set the color
        label_test_name.setPadding(5,5,5,5); // set the padding (if required)
        tr_head.addView(label_test_name); // add the column to the table row here

        TextView label_test_date = new TextView(this);
        label_test_date.setId(21);// define id that must be unique
        label_test_date.setText("Date"); // set the text for the header 
        label_test_date.setTextColor(Color.WHITE); // set the color
        label_test_date.setPadding(5,5,5,5); // set the padding (if required)
        tr_head.addView(label_test_date); // add the column to the table row here



        report_table.addView(tr_head, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

      //---------------Table Header-----------------------------------------------



        //--------------------Table Body---------------------------
        for (int i=1; i<=10; i++)
        {
            tr_data = new TableRow(this);
            tr_data.setId(10);
            tr_data.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            tr_data.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


            TextView sr_no = new TextView(this);
            sr_no.setId(20);
            sr_no.setText(""+i);
            sr_no.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            sr_no.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
            tr_data.addView(sr_no);// add the column to the table row here

            TextView test_name = new TextView(this);
            test_name.setId(21);// define id that must be unique
            test_name.setText("Speed Test 60(min) Demo-ST-01"); // set the text for the header 
            test_name.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); // set the color
            test_name.setPadding(5,5,5,5); // set the padding (if required)
            tr_data.addView(test_name); // add the column to the table row here

            TextView test_date = new TextView(this);
            test_date.setId(21);// define id that must be unique
            test_date.setText("12 Mar 2013"); // set the text for the header 
            test_date.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); // set the color
            test_date.setPadding(5,5,5,5); // set the padding (if required)
            tr_data.addView(test_date); // add the column to the table row here



            report_table.addView(tr_data, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }

      //--------------------Table Body---------------------------


    }


}
```

Here is the **layout file**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".ReportListActivity" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TableLayout
                    android:shrinkColumns="0,1,2"
                    android:id="@+id/report_table" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent">
            </TableLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**How should I implement onclick listener to the table data except the header row and get the data of all columns of the particular row?**

I followed [this](http://technotzz.wordpress.com/2011/11/04/android-dynamically-add-rows-to-table-layout/) tutorial!

Comment: Have u setClickable to true for each TableRow? and then setOnClickListener?

Comment: The rows are added dynamically, so onclick listner can not be set in XML

Comment: So u can do the same in code. tr_head.setOnClickListener method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put `setOnClickListener` on tr_data and also all TextView `final`

```
final TextView test_name = new TextView(this);
            test_name.setId(21);// define id that must be unique
            test_name.setText("Speed Test 60(min) Demo-ST-01"); // set the text for the header 
            test_name.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); // set the color
            test_name.setPadding(5,5,5,5); // set the padding (if required)
            tr_data.addView(test_name); // add the column to the table row here


 report_table.addView(tr_data, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            tr_data.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    String test_name1= test_name.getText().toString();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), test_name1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Please can you elaborate a little?

Comment: Add setOnclickListener and create textView final. problem solved

Comment: Not working, if you do not mind, can you please edit my given class?

Comment: Put xml file in your question

Comment: I am getting this error The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){})

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27537/discussion-between-nirav-ranpara-and-kittu88)

Comment: Hey, can you please help me out with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15811472/freeze-one-table-column-horizontally?noredirect=1#comment22488541_15811472

Answer (score 0):

You have to setOnClickListener to the Row  Added Dynamically i.e. you have to add SetOnclickListener in For Loop where you are setting the Table Body dynamically

check below your edited code

```
//--------------------Table Body---------------------------
    for (int i=1; i<=10; i++)
    {
        tr_data = new TableRow(this);
        tr_data.setId(10);
        tr_data.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        **tr_data.setOnClickListener(this);**  //set on clickListener to Row here
}
```

hope this help you.